# Why do some commands terminate when leaving the minibuffer (isearch) while others don't (find-file)?

Tags: minibuffer, recursive-edit

Occasionally I start to open a file, and before I select the file for some reason I execute <kbd>C-x o</kbd> before answering the prompt. Then everytime I try and run `find-file` again it complains about *Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer*. However if I use a command like `isearch-forward-regexp`, (even if already in a `find-file` prompt), the error is not thrown and I can't switch back to the minibuffer using `other-window`.
**Why is it that some prompts temporarily upgrade the minibuffer so that `other-window` considers the minibuffer a possible target, and others do not?**

---

Just to clarify, I’m not asking *how* to get unstuck.
Originally when I encountered this, I would switch to the minibuffer and do <kbd>Esc Esc Esc</kbd> or <kbd>C-g</kbd> to escape the prompt, so that I could initiate a new command that uses the minibuffer. However, on pondering this question, I realized that `abort-recursive-edit` (<kbd>C-]</kbd>) will close this minibuffer in progress without having to do `other-window` + `keyboard-quit`.

Still, I'm not quite sure what the original use case is for. Perhaps, it’s meant to aid in copy pasting into a minibuffer prompt, or to assist running a command in the middle of a macro?

What I *do* want to know is if there is a way to disable this recursivity the way it is with `isearch`. Is `isearch` safe because it's using read-event instead of a blocking prompt? Is there a hook to trigger `abort-recursive-edit` when exiting the minibuffer?

---

**TL;DR**

1. Why do some minibuffer commands upgrade the minibuffer to a target for `other-window`, and block running new minibuffer commands, while others, such as `isearch`, do not?
2. Is there a way to disable this?
3. What is this feature's intended use case?

Comment: Your question is unclear, to me. Just what are you trying to do? `C-]` aborts one level of minibuffer, yes. Isearch does not use the minibuffer. And what does "**stuck in prompt**" have to do with any of the rest of what you describe? You should not need to use `switch-window` at all, in such contexts. But it is not clear what you are trying to do. Try to separate the various pieces of your description, and try to come up with a single question.

Comment: Try setting `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to `t` to avoid the *Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer* message. It might help clarify the original question, if you posted the question on `recursive-edit` separately.

Answer (score 5):

1. Many interactive commands read minibuffer input.  `find-file` is one such
   command.  Reading minibuffer input "activates" the minibuffer window, which
   is why you can switch to it with the `other-window` command.  Interactive
   `isearch` is special because it's implemented as a minor mode.  It doesn't
   technically read your search string from the minibuffer, but instead
   catches your keypresses as you type and echoes them to the minibuffer with
   `message`.  This is why you see `other-window` behaving differently.
2. This may or may not help you, but technically you can modify the prompt
   behavior of `find-file` by modifying the function stored in
   `read-file-name-function`.  I haven't tried advising the function based on
   @kaushalmodi's answer, but if that works I'll update this.
3. I can't speak for any of the hackers who worked on the code in
   minibuffer.el, but from the following description in the
   [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-Edit.html)  I'd guess the behavior is designed to let you kill-and-yank text:

> When the minibuffer is active, the echo area is treated much like an
>   ordinary Emacs window. For instance, you can switch to another window (with
>   C-x o), edit text there, then return to the minibuffer window to finish the
>   argument. You can even kill text in another window, return to the minibuffer
>   window, and yank the text into the argument.

Answer (score 2):

The below snippet [[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022880/how-can-i-prevent-the-mini-buffer-from-displaying-previous-commands-in-emacs)] aborts recursive edit when focus moves away from the minibuffer. This is to avoid the irritating occassions where repeated `C-g` pressing doesn't edit the mini-buffer as cursor focus has moved out of it.

```
(defun stop-using-minibuffer ()
  "kill the minibuffer"
  (when (and (>= (recursion-depth) 1) (active-minibuffer-window))
    (abort-recursive-edit)))
(add-hook 'mouse-leave-buffer-hook 'stop-using-minibuffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Drew has already commented on this, but...

`isearch`<sup>1</sup> doesn't actually use the minibuffer, which probably accounts for part of your confusion.  It displays things in the echo area (which is in the same *window* as the minibuffer, but isn't actually the minibuffer).

That being the case, the notion of switching to and from the minibuffer while running an isearch doesn't make any sense.

<sup>1</sup> Ignoring commands like `isearch-edit-string` which *do* use the minibuffer, but aren't part of the most basic isearch workflow.