# why do I need to use ctrl-G twice to quit a minibuffer prompt?

Tags: minibuffer, quitting

Sometime recently emacs started making me hit `C-g` twice to quit a minibuffer prompt and I can't figure out how or why it's doing this.

What happens is I start a minibuffer command -- say, `C-x C-f` -- and then hit `C-g` to quit. Emacs then appends "`[Quit]` to the end of the minibuffer prompt, and doing `C-g` quits as expected.

It's the `[Quit]` that strikes me. I think that's related to some package I tried, but I don't see anything in my configuration.

I'm using emacs 27.1 on Windows.

There are several seemingly-related questions to this --

- [Why do some commands terminate when leaving the minibuffer (isearch) while others don't (find-file)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/812/why-do-some-commands-terminate-when-leaving-the-minibuffer-isearch-while-other)
- [C-g has stopped breaking out of commands like `C-x C-f` and `M-x` in graphical emacs-25](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34084/c-g-has-stopped-breaking-out-of-commands-like-c-x-c-f-and-m-x-in-graphical-e)
- [Need double c-g to quit from a minibuffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26672/need-double-c-g-to-quit-from-a-minibuffer)

...but they seem to be about Linux, or GTK, or something else.

What package or configuration might cause this behavior?

Comment: Does it happen with `emacs -q`? If not, you can bisect your init file to find out who the culprit is. FWIW, I don't see that in the simple case, although it might happen with recursive edits in the minibuffer: you might have to `C-g` out of each level of the recursive edit.

Comment: What @NickD said - try `emacs -Q`. Bisect your init file.

Comment: Are you using any of the completion engines (ivy, ido, helm)? I am seeing the same thing and my feeling is that it's related to ivy/counsel but I am not sure.

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, starting with `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 1):

This was a dependency package -- [org-random-todo](https://github.com/unhammer/org-random-todo) depends on [alert](https://github.com/jwiegley/alert). Uninstalling and reinstalling `org-random-todo` seems to have cleared up the problem. So something in the installation seems to have gotten mixed up.